# Installment and Season difference

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, difference

I noticed a TV show in a streaming app that basically has 2 seasons, but I'm wondering why do they use the word differently i.e. season and installment (instalment if it's British according to OALD)

[image]

I did look the words up, and from the dictionary, installment can also mean **episode** which once made me think twice when there was an ad of this TV show that told there's a new installment and I thought the second episode of the second season has already come out, and in the end I realised the ad meant to tell that the first episode of the second season is the one that's already available.

Regardless, are those two words synonymous? Or is it just the app that uses the word incorrectly?

Comment: FYI the Hulu application and web site call it Season 2. This seems to be specific to the app you're using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Installment" is used in **film series**.

> Instalment is used much less frequently for film series than episode is for television. [Source](https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/instalment-vs-episode.2877936/)

But it isn't used very frequently.

Answer (score 3):

According to [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/es/diccionario/ingles/installment), an installment is

> one of several parts into which a story, plan, or amount of money owed has been divided, so that each part happens or is paid at different times until the end or total is reached.

I no longer follow AHS, so I have no more context, but I understand that it's not a season nor an episode but rather the first delivery of the story.